# Community Promotion Ads on the SE Network

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Throughout the SE Network, there are meta posts for Community Promotion Ads. Their objective, among other things related to the context of each site, is to promote "anything else your community would genuinely be interested in".
As such, it would be interesting to promote Anime & Manga over at the other SE sites.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

---

**So far, we have posted ads at:**

- [**Arqade**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013/6780#6780)
- [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2535/6365)
- [**Role-Playing Games**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013/2774#2774)

**These will rotate their image every week or so**, so as to both not flood the other sites with our ads, and to be able to display 'fresh' images.

---

This site does not yet have ads from us, but **it could also be of interest to promote A&M there**:

- [**Game Development**](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/983/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Comment: Shouldn't there be some requirement about not using copyrighted images? I mean, I know it happens all the time online, but for something "official" like this, I'm not so sure if it's OK.

Comment: @atlantiza It is **not OK unless** you have permission, which can come either through the rights owner or by law through [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Comment: After clearing up some of the fog. Avoid using a copyrighted image as much as possible. It's not really fair use -- you're not commenting on the work at all, just appropriating the image.

Comment: Then this should be added to the guidelines and the Cowboy Bebop ad should be removed.

Comment: @atlantiza and others: See [this post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-do-we-deal-with-copyrighted-material-on-our-site) if concerned with copyright infringement issues.

Comment: @JNat I think using a copyrighted image to advertise a site is "something obviously boneheaded."

Comment: @atlantiza The relevant chat discussion is [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/more-on-copyright-4-chat-cast). Personally I still think we should avoid using copyrighted artwork in our ads as much as possible, though not for legal reasons. On the other hand, the consensus at the time was that we shouldn't worry about it. If you want to try to reverse that, I think the best thing to do is to create a separate meta thread on the issue, and we can have the discussion there. The comments section on this post isn't really the best place to be having the discussion IMO.

Comment: I'm closing this question because we have at least one newer version of this post (http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/761/), and I don't want Community to bump it again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Anime and Manga SE]

Comment: This is an example of an answer, already posted at Arqade.