# Community Ads on the network, 2014 edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We had [community ads](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/community-promotion-ads-on-the-se-network) on three network sites this past year, namely [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), [Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), and [Role-Playing Games](http://rpg.stackexchange.com). These refresh every year, so we'll need to post them again to any sites that we want them.

There are some meta questions we should answer regarding these. Last year, we more-or-less decided on these in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga), but it's really more appropriate to hold the discussion on meta. Here are some examples:

- Do we want community ads? (Probably, but keep in mind that unlike a year ago, we aren't exactly having a hard time bringing in traffic now so we may not need them.)
- Which sites should we post community ads on? Which ads should we use on each of these sites?
- How many different ads should we have? (Last year we had several, but having too many may come off negatively)
- Are the existing ones from 2013 sufficient, or do we need to design new ones?

Feel free to post as an answer your ideas to any of the above questions or any suggested ads (new or recycled). The main goal of this meta post is to coordinate our promotional efforts via community ads in the network.

Here are the specifications for the ads (taken verbatim from the above post):

---

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Answer (score 3):

[image: Sword Art Online]

Comment: Have you posted this one anywhere? I like it, but the bottom text is a big hard to read and doesn't stand out. Is there anything you can do to increase the contrast of that text?

Comment: @LoganM I am not very good with image editing.  I am horrible at figuring out the minor adjustments so let me know if this is any better.  Also, I have not posted it anywhere but you (and anyone else) are free to post it wherever you want.

Comment: I can't tell which I prefer. Putting them side by side, I actually think the old version might have just a bit more contrast, but both of them are fine IMO. As for posting it, I was thinking it could go well on Arqade and/or maybe game design. I'll post it in a few days if no one else does so before me.

Answer (score 2):

[image: No no Kuni]

Comment: [Copied from Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8064/42984)

Answer (score 1):

I've reposted the one we used on RPG.SE and two on Scifi since there were no complaints and no better suggestions for these sites. While we now have 7 ads that I know of, I didn't see much need to post more than that. The purpose of these ads is to make sure that regular Scifi/RPG users are aware of our site, not to flood their site in an attempt to bring in traffic (which we're doing pretty well on).

Click the ads for links to their respective posts. If you have an account on these sites I'd encourage you to vote for them so that other related SE communities will continue to be aware of us.

RPG:

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Scifi:

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]
[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]